# Errors in terminal when deploying to heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I''m brand new to all this stuff and I am trying to deploy just a simple website using python to heroku.

I get the following error:

```
 at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=arcane-lake-2908.herokuapp.com fwd="71.20.1.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
 2013-09-03T09:47:58.419844+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=arcane-lake-2908.herokuapp.com fwd="71.20.1.73" dyno=   connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I also see something that sees "reason worker failed to boot".

The last 2 commands I ran were:
      Scale to web=1
      heroku open

Comment: Did you try running your app locally with `foreman`? Something might be wrong with your `Procfile`

Comment: I just went back and looked through what I did in terminal and the first time I ran foreman it said gunicorn wasn't installed.  I installed gunicorn and ran foreman again and what i get now is:  ImportError:  No Module named hello.   Also, worth noting, I am able to run my program with no errors and go to localhost:8080 to see it.  It seems like I messed up with the heroku stuff.

Comment: what happens if you run `gunicorn hello:app` directly from command line ?

Answer (score 2):

Your Procfile is incorrect.

You have something like

```
web: gunicorn hello:app
```

You should replace `hello` by the name of your app