# Heroku ImportError: No Module named hello

Tags: python, heroku

So I just created my first little website with python, virtualenv and lpthw.web.
When I run python bin/app.py, I can go to my browser to localhost:8080 and it works no problem.

However, after setting up Heroku, when I run Foreman I get:
     ImportError: No Module named hello.

I don't know if this is relevant but I tried to deploy it to heroku anyway, and when I type heroku open I get:

```
  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=arcane-lake- 2908.herokuapp.com fwd="71.20.1.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
  2013-09-03T09:47:58.419844+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=arcane-lake-2908.herokuapp.com fwd="71.20.1.73" dyno=   connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Did you do proper `__init__.py` setups?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Errors in terminal when deploying to heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601793/errors-in-terminal-when-deploying-to-heroku)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, and it's a simple fix. Just take a look at your Procfile. It probably shows something like

```
web: gunicorn hello:app
```

You should replace `hello` by the name of your app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'hello' module in settings>installed apps

Comment: what settings ? what installed apps ?

Answer (score 0):

open your project directory and there you wiil find  settings.py and there you can see like below

> INSTALLED_APPS = (
>          'django.contrib.admin',
>          'django.contrib.auth',
>          'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>          'django.contrib.sessions',
>          'django.contrib.messages',
>          'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>          'Your app name here',
>   )